# Why does Cygwin ignore python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin

I'm trying to run Python 3 on Cygwin *(windows 8)* but for some reason , It recognizes only Python 2. Can I separately download python and put it in same folder in the Cygwin folder in program files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the default version of python as a `2.x` version instead of your `3.x` version but this can be fixed by a quick system hack:

Goto `My Computer -----> System properties -----> Advanced System settings -----> Advanced -----> Environment Variables` and then check if the variable **path** contains your python2 *(default : C:\Python27)* installation path if so remove it first and then **replace it with your python3 *(default : C:\Python33)* installation directory**

Comment: my path has a lot more directories after C: and before python 33, but python33 is there

Comment: @Asher Obviously The `path` variable contains lots of directories *that's how its supposed to be* and are separated by `;` wooah but is `C:\Python33` already there??

Comment: Yes, python 3 is there.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know details about Cygwin distribution of Python 3.3, but the official distribution of Python 3.3 for Windows contains *Python Launcher for Windows* -- in the form of py.exe and pyw.exe located in c:\Windows. During the installation, the `.py` and `.pyw` extensions are associated with the launcher. If the script does not contains the `#!python3` as the first line, the Python launcher starts the highest found version of Python 2.x.

The chance is that or the Python launcher is also part of the Cygwin distribution, or you had the non-Cygwin version installed earlier; hence the launcher and the association is already active (and you do not know).

How exactly do you execute your script? Try to add the magic line `#!python3` as the very first line of the script.